# Указать Generic тип в абстрактном классе

Tags: java, generics

У меня есть 2 класса, AbstractJobManager который выдаёт работу, и AbsractJob соотвественно сама работа. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы эти классы были связанны друг с другом, то есть указать как generic тип у AbstractJobManager работу которую он выдаёт, а у самой работы указать как generic тип менеджер, так как в дальшейшем хочу получать manager у объекта работы.
Те нужно сделать как то так:

```
public abstract class AbstractJobManager<J extends AbstractJob<ТЕКУЩИЙ КЛАСС>>
public abstract class AbstractJob<M extends AbstractJobManager<ТЕКУЩИЙ КЛАСС>>
```

Чтобы потом можно было сделать метод в AbstractJob, где M это менеджер

```
public final M getJobManager() {}
```

А так же метод в AbstractJobManager где J это работа игрока

```
 public J getPlayerJob(Player player) {}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Абстрактный класс менеджера

```
public abstract class AbstractJobManager<J extends AbstractJob<? extends AbstractJobManager<J>>>
```

Абстрактный класс работы

```
public abstract class AbstractJob<M extends AbstractJobManager<? extends AbstractJob<M>>>
```

Например, если мне нужно будет сделать работу такси, то выглядеть это будет так

Класс менеджера

```
public class TaxiManager extends AbstractJobManager<TaxiJob>
```

Класс работы

```
public class TaxiJob extends AbstractJob<TaxiManager>
```